# Should we be using connection pooling with HTTP/2

Tags: java, connection-pooling, okhttp, http2

We recently switched from HTTP/1 to HTTP/2 for our server communication and using OKHTTP library on the client to talk to the server.

```
this.client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .protocols(Protocol.H2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE)


       .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT))
        .build();
```

Previously we were using connection pools with Http1. Now with multiplexing feature with HTTP2 I am not sure if its a good idea to use a connection pool and how it would work anyways.

Any advise on some pros and cons of using a connection pool with Http2 and any general guidelines on how to tune it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes: [Do we still need a connection pool for microservices talking HTTP2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55985658/do-we-still-need-a-connection-pool-for-microservices-talking-http2/55987161#55987161)

In the answer above you will find references to HTTP/2 clients (since they are used to invoke other microservices) and how to tune the HTTP/2 flow control window.

Comment: So this is a duplicate?

Comment: It's a slight different scenario (client-only vs microservices - which are typically server-side), but almost everything said in that answer applies to the client as well. It's not a duplicate question IMHO, just a duplicate _answer_ :)